# Can we give dynamic queryset for ModelChoiceField in django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want create a model form, which has a foreign key in the model. Like:

```
class TestModel(Model):
    field1=ForeignKey(RefModel)
```

I create a form like:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = TestModel
        widgets = {'field1': RadioSelect}
```

But I want to do some limitation on the field according to the url, which means it's not constant data, what should I do to change the queryset for field1 of TestForm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the field.
use

```
field1 = ModelChoiceField(queryset=<<your_queryset_here>>, widget=RadioSelect)
```

you can also override this queryset in the `__init__` method and adjusting the field accordingly:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    field1 = ModelChoiceField(queryset=<<your_queryset_here>>, widget=RadioSelect)

    class Meta(object):
        model = TestModel

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields['field1'].queryset = kwargs.pop('field1_qs')
```

and initiating the form accordingly in the view that manages it.

```
my_form = TestForm(field1_qs=MyQS)
```

Comment: This really helps a lot, the second method is what I eager for. I knew the first method and tried to modify testform_instance.field1.queryset, but it said there is no such an attribute, it's strange issue since we have define such an attribute of field1. I also try to define a field1 in __init__, it doesn't work either.